# web3js invalid address

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I deploy a contract on Rinkeby using geth. I am trying to interact with it using node.

When the contract is deployed, I call a simple function that changes a value in my contract:

```
uint public value1;

    function changeValue(uint newValue) public {
        value1 = newValue;
    }
```

the problem is that I get a "Invalid address" error.

- The account is unlocked
- The default address of web is set to the address I want to call this function from
- Even using "from" in the call method, I get the error.

http://prntscr.com/gwssrd

Can someone explain me why?

PS: By the way, I am doing the exact same manipulations as someone else (just with a different contract), and it works for my pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It was a mistake (obviously :D ) from me, nothing to do with web3.

Instead of using the contract address, I used the transac hash... And of course, did not work as expected.